# Why does uploading file doesn't work with error checking?

Tags: php

I just referred [this doc](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for error handling .

**code**

```
 /*foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    print_r($error);
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);
    }
  }*/

  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) 
  {
    die('{"success":"The file ".  basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]).  has been uploaded"}');
  }else
  {
    die('{"error" :  "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"}');
  }
```

If i use the commented part instead uncommented, my file is not uploading. But i referred the documentation to handle size, extension errors. Please let me know if i understood anything wrongly.

And nothing gets printed if i try `print_r($_FILES)` in the console.
How do i make my forst method working.

Comment: No. It's not working. It's a typo. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wanna tun a `foreach` loop?

In the else condition itself you can check whether the files got uploaded or not. `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` wil return 0 if the upload was successful else it wont.

```
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) 
  {
    die('{"success":"The file ".  basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]).  has been uploaded"}');
  }else
  {
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] != 0) {
     die('{"error" :  "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"}');
  }
```

**EDIT**

You can also check even if any file was uploaded or whether the uploaded file exceeded the file size limit using `$_FILES["file"]["size"]`

**NOTE:**

If you want to run a foreachloop, you can try this,

```
 foreach ($_FILES['file'] as $file) {

    if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $fileName = $file['name'];
        $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $image_name = 'image_' . $file['name'] . '1';
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_dir . $image_name); 

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. How do i handle if it returns some other number. For that purpose, i used foreach loop.

Comment: If it doesnt return 0, just use an else condition, why a foreach loop? Its unnecessary

Comment: check my latest edit if you want to run a foreach loop..In your commented code, you need to add '$key' in move_uploaded_file(
         $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"][$key],
         $target_path_to_store_file
       )

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you try adding [$key] in $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"] ? It would be good if you could update your ques with the errors that you are getting

Comment: Yes, I just used more print_r to identify the cause. It says `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and i just printed out my `$_FILES` it prints `[type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => C:\Users\gopir\AppData\Local\Temp\php4CD4.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 241`

Comment: Are you uploading single file or multiple files?

Comment: just print_r($_FILES["file"]["error"]); and see what you get

Comment: It prints `0` as same as in the array i have added above

Comment: hey..checkout the edit in my answer. you dont even have to loop the $_FILES["file"]["error"], just loop the $_FILES['file']

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things going wrong if as you say the $_FILES global array is blank. I would start by checking:

1) Do you have the enctype properly set on the form to enctype='multipart/form-data'?
2) If php.ini max post size variable is less than the size of the file, no error will be thrown...it will simply fail. Try adding the following overrides to you .htaccess file in the site root.

post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M

Replace 20M with however large you want the files uploaded to be at maximum. You can echo ini_get("post_max_size") to make sure it overrides php.ini.